# Does duplicity detect when a Backup Is Already In-Progress?

Tags: backup, cron, duplicity, schedule

Any time you schedule a recurring backup, it is always possible for a previously-initiated-backup to run so long that the next scheduled backup gets initiated before the previous backup completes.

Given the concept of duplicity's backup-chains, does duplicity inherently check to see if a backup is already in-progress before allowing an additional attempt to modify that same backup chain?

I'm aware of solutions to prevent this (outside of duplicity), but my question is does duplicity's code already inherently address this concern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of 0.6.23, duplicity will do file locking on the cache directory associated with the backup.  It is possible to have two duplicity instances running as long as they are different backups.  Duplicity will not allow overlap of the same backup.

The previous versions would not detect the problem and that would potentially cause problems when trying to restore the overlapping backups.

...Ken (Duplicity Maintainer)